# Convert Chinese characters into other charset

Tags: c#, string

I have this string : `ç²¾é¸ç å¯¶ä½?å?/é»?ké??`
I want to convert it into something like : `作品/黃k金`

I've used a lot of methods to decode this but without success. I precise that this string is part of an URL. The server send to me with `301 redirect (in the location header)`, I'd like to decode it in order to parse the URL.

**Here is what I have been trying :**

```
string text = "ç²¾é¸ç å¯¶ä½?å?/é»?ké??";
string decoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(text);
```

**I've also tried this method, but without success:**

```
public static string HtmlEncode(string text)
    {
        string result;
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var x = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            x.WriteEncodedText(text);
            result = sw.ToString();
        }
        return result;

    }
```

The header gives me a non utf8 charset (iso-8859-1), I also tried an UTF-8 conversion, but with no success...

```
Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;

byte[] isoBytes = iso.GetBytes(text);
byte[] utfBytes = Encoding.Convert(iso, utf8, isoBytes);
return utf8.GetString(utfBytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "ç²¾é¸ç å¯¶ä½?å?/é»?ké??";    
            byte[] origBytes = new byte[str.Length];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (char c in str)
            {
                origBytes[i++] = (byte)c;
            }
            Encoding origEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(936);
            Encoding newEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            byte[] newBytes = Encoding.Convert(origEncoding, newEncoding, origBytes);
            string res = newEncoding.GetString(newBytes);
        }
```

Output

[image]

Comment: thank you @Neel i'll try this tomorrow and will tell you if it worked for me.

Comment: i tried the solution. i think you're not far from the final solution :)
i tested this string : 

`ç³»å/ç å¯¶/ç²¾é¸ç å¯¶ä½å`

and the result was :

`绯诲垪/鐝犲/绮鹃伕鐝犲浣滃搧`

As you can see, there are 2 small square in the middle which are not decoded. it seems to be blank characters